# to get leaf nodes directly in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

in a complex XML where I dont know the leaf node names/or the level of depth they are, how could I extract all the leaf nodes inside a XMLList variable directly?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share an example xml structure, or you want this to be generic?

Comment: I want it to be generic... I know I could use some kind of recursive function to check if the node has any childs and keep it doing until I get to leaf node (storing all such leaf nodes in a separate xmllist variable). But this sounds tiresome and boring. I was looking for a shorter cleaner method which could use some ECMA syntax and do it easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has replied so far, I am assuming that there is no easy using ECMA to achieve this for a generic XML... and that leaves UDF as the only choice (the function would recursively keep checking if there are any childs left - if not then its a leaf).

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
        /**
         * function to check for the leaf nodes and return 
         * an XMLListCollection of leaf nodes. Give it 
         * your xml and an empty object of XMLListCollection for result.
         **/
        private function leafNodes(x:XML, retList:XMLListCollection):void {
            var xlist:XMLList;
            xlist = x.children();

            if (x.children().length() == 0) { // leaf node
                retList.addItem(x);
                return;
            }

            for each (var it:XML in xlist) 
                leafNodes(it, retList);

            return;
        }
```